# How to get margin value of a div in plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, margin

I can get height in jQuery with

```
$(item).outerHeight(true);
```

but how do I with JS?

I can get the height of the li with

```
document.getElementById(item).offsetHeight
```

but i will always get "" when I try margin-top:

```
document.getElementById(item).style.marginTop
```

Answer (score 165, accepted):

The properties on the `style` object are only the styles applied directly to the element (e.g., via a `style` attribute or in code). So `.style.marginTop` will only have something in it if you have something specifically assigned to that element (not assigned via a style sheet, etc.).

To get the current calculated style of the object, you use either the [`currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property (Microsoft) or the [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) function (pretty much everyone else).

Example:

```
var p = document.getElementById("target");
var style = p.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(p);

display("Current marginTop: " + style.marginTop);
```

Fair warning: What you get back may not be in pixels. For instance, if I run the above on a `p` element in IE9, I get back `"1em"`.

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/alurok/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/alurok/1/edit)

Comment: Thank you T.J., i tried on FF and Chrome, it works. I thought `getComputedStyle()` was a method of element node at first, turns out it is a method of `window`. I would try on IE later.

Comment: As you said, this only works when original unit is in 'px'. Do you have any solution to get the real value?

Comment: @vsync: No, it works regardless of the original value's units, but what you *receive* may well be (or may not be) in pixels instead. I'm not aware of a way to reliably get a non-pixels value short of working through the CSS rules yourself.

Comment: The method `getComputedStyle()` will always return "resolved values", i.e. it always returns a pixel value, regardless of the unit used in the CSS rule

Answer (score 12):

Also, you can create your own `outerHeight` for HTML elements. I don't know if it works in IE, but it works in Chrome. Perhaps, you can enhance the code below using `currentStyle`, suggested in the answer above.

```
Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'outerHeight', {
    'get': function(){
        var height = this.clientHeight;
        var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(this); 
        height += parseInt(computedStyle.marginTop, 10);
        height += parseInt(computedStyle.marginBottom, 10);
        height += parseInt(computedStyle.borderTopWidth, 10);
        height += parseInt(computedStyle.borderBottomWidth, 10);
        return height;
    }
});
```

This piece of code allow you to do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('foo').outerHeight
```

According to [caniuse.com, getComputedStyle](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getcomputedstyle) is supported by main browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox).

Comment: I don't think IE supports window.getComputedStyle method, thanks anyway.

Comment: `getComputedStyle` is available for IE ≥ 9

Comment: But i am living in a country where you must deal with IE6 (┬＿┬)

Comment: getComputedStyle is very slow. You should avoid needlessly recalling it like this.

Comment: @JosephLennox do you know how does jQuery do?

Answer (score 11):

Here  is my solution:

**Step 1: Select the element**

**Step 2: Use getComputedStyle and provide the element to it**

**Step 3: Now access all the properties**

```
const item = document.getElementbyId('your-element-id');
const style= getComputedStyle(item);
const itemTopmargin = style.marginTop;
console.log(itemTopmargin)
```

It will give you margin with **px** units like "16px" which you might not want.
You can extract the value using **`parseInt()`**

```
const marginTopNumber = parseInt(itemTopmargin)
console.log(marginTopNumber)
```

It will give you the numerical value only (without any units).

Answer (score 9):

I found something very useful on this site when I was searching for an answer on this question. You can check it out at http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/230503-how-get-margin-left-value.html. The part that helped me was the following:

```js
/***
 * get live runtime value of an element's css style
 *   http://robertnyman.com/2006/04/24/get-the-rendered-style-of-an-element
 *     note: "styleName" is in CSS form (i.e. 'font-size', not 'fontSize').
 ***/
var getStyle = function(e, styleName) {
  var styleValue = "";
  if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
    styleValue = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(e, "").getPropertyValue(styleName);
  } else if (e.currentStyle) {
    styleName = styleName.replace(/\-(\w)/g, function(strMatch, p1) {
      return p1.toUpperCase();
    });
    styleValue = e.currentStyle[styleName];
  }
  return styleValue;
}
////////////////////////////////////
var e = document.getElementById('yourElement');
var marLeft = getStyle(e, 'margin-left');
console.log(marLeft);    // 10px
```

```css
#yourElement {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="yourElement"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your method is similar to T.J. Crowder, but you wrap it into a function. ^_^