# keyboard Event :Moving div to left with margin-left on pressing key

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I would like to move to the left a div when pressing left keybord arrow.

```
function arrowright (event){
    var vaiss= document.getElementById("vaisseau");
    var size= vaiss.style.marginLeft;
    alert(size); //here I get empty message
    if (event.which==39)
        vaiss.style.marginLeft=size+"5px";
    alert (vaiss.style.marginLeft); // here I get 5px not previous left margin + 5px
}
```

Here CSS:

```
#vaisseau{
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:300px;
    display;block;
}
```

And HTML:

```
div id="vaisseau" class="elements"><img src="vaisseau.jpg"></div>
```

I think The problem is that it don't read the actual value of margin-left.

EDIT: the css style is in an external file

Comment: Are errors displayed on the developper console? ( [F12] key on most browsers)

Comment: no error, when pressing key the margin-left became equal to 5px, I would that I will be equal to : actual value + 5px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer here : [How to get margin value of a div in plain JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275304/how-to-get-margin-value-of-a-div-in-original-javascript)

T.J. Crowder said :

> The properties on the `style` object are only the styles applied directly to the element (e.g., via a style attribute or in code). So `.style.marginTop` will only have something in it if you have something specifically assigned to that element (not assigned via a style sheet, etc.).
>
> To get the current calculated style of the object, you use either the
>   `currentStyle` property (Microsoft) or the `getComputedStyle` function
>   (pretty much everyone else).

Example:

```
var p = document.getElementById("target");
var style = p.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(p);

display("Current marginTop: " + style.marginTop);
```

To summarize :

`document.getElementById("vaisseau").style.marginLeft` only works when the HTML code looks like this : `<div id="vaisseau" class="elements" style="margin-left: 300px"></div>`